# Partial "Melt" or "Unstack" Non-Index Columns or

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| ethnicity_name | enrollment | teacher_salary | ethnicity_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| African_American | 513 | 102000 | .10 |
| Caucasian | 513 | 102000 | .26 |
| Hispanic | 513 | 102000 | .64 |

I need to "unstack" the first column (ethnicity_name) into three additional columns, and fill the values of those columns with "ethnicity_percent" values.

The final dataframe should look like this:

| enrollment | teacher_salary | African_American | Caucasian | Hispanic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 513 | 102000 | .10 | .26 | .64 |

I can think of the following two ways of doing this, which are hackneyed:

1. pd.get_dummies and then df.map on the original names column to the values column
2. turn the 'ethnicity_name' column into an index, and unstack, and then map

I'm a beginner, so I have faith that there must be some better way. TIA.

Comment: try `pivot` : ``df.pivot(['enrollment', 'teacher_salary'], 'ethnicity_name', 'ethnicity_percent')``

Comment: Thank you! Let's say that I had another pair of columns in the same dataframe, with the same issue, would the syntax be: df.pivot(['enrollment', 'teacher_salary'], [('ethnicity_name', 'ethnicity_percent'),('hypothetical_name','hypothetical_value')]) ?